# K&R different outputs from basically the same thing

Tags: c

I am currently working through K&R for C. In section 1.5, we basically create a program for word count. The code is as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c;
    long int nl, nc, nw;
    int state;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    state = OUT;
    while((c = getchar())!= EOF){
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n'){
          ++nl;
        }
        if (c == ' '||c == '\n'|| c == '\t'){
          state = OUT;
        } else if (state == OUT){
          state = IN;
          ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%ld %ld %ld\n", nl, nc, nw);
}
```

When I compile this program with gcc and open the executable and type something such as

```
Hello
World
```

I get output

```
1 11 2
```

Which makes sense as we have 1 '\n' newline characters, 11 characters (including newline), and 2 word. What is interesting is when I do

```
vim hello.txt
```

and type

```
Hello
World
```

and then issue the command

```
cat hello.txt|./a.out
```

I get the following output

```
2 12 2
```

Why are the outputs from this different from before because all I am doing is streaming the file into the executable so I do not understand what is different. Please do explain.

Thank You.

Comment: Please post the output from `od -c hello.lxt`

Comment: Thank you so much, turns out, the editor places a '\n' character after 
'World'. I do not know why it is. But that explains it...

Comment: When you ran the program interactively, did you end the second line with Enter and then end the input with Ctrl-D (like a normal person), or leave the cursor hanging in the middle of the line and end the input by typing Ctrl-D twice (like some kind of newline-hating barbarian)?

Comment: Yes thank you all so much, that explains it. I had left my cursor on the same line as 'World'. On the other hand, does this mean that my editor placed a '\n' character right before EOF because when I checked the file hello.txt only contained my phrase and no line following 'World'.

Comment: When you see 2 lines with text on them in a text file, they both end in a newline. If they didn't, they wouldn't be *lines*.

Comment: When I edit the file with nano, I see that there is an edition of newline that I cannot delete, it seems that vim just hides this from you...

Comment: There seem to be two schools of thought on files whose last lines are missing newlines.  Traditionally, Unix considered the newlines as a *terminator*, not a *separator*; files without trailing newlines were distinctly odd, and some programs mishandled them.  Today, though, there seem to be decently-large swaths of the computer-using universe that consider files without trailing newlines to be perfectly normal.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - What is a normal person?

Comment: What’s the reason of checking **c** two times for **\n**?

Comment: BTW - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch9UuMFwzCE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not your program's feature, but Vim's. See: [What does the noeol indicator at the bottom of a vim edit session mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31807/211239)

Vim automatically appends a newline at the end of file if there isn't  when saving.

Type

```
:set noeol
```

in Vim and save the file again, then your program will output 11 as the second number.

P.S. It's redundant to use `cat something | program`, just `program < something` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Yeah and I see now that it may be better to stream it like you said.

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug. Text files without a `'\n'` at the end of the last line can cause problems. For example, if you type `cat file.txt`, your shell prompt will be concatenated onto the end of the last line of the output.

Comment: @KeithThompson I know. It's kinda standard feature for a Unix editor.

Answer (score 1):

After you type the charactors into the file and save it, at the end of the file, a 0x0a is added to the end of the file automaticly

Comment: It's clearer to refer to `'\n'` rather than `0xa`, and you didn't mention that it's vim that does this.